# What can I use to configure IP addresses?

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, hotspot

I have set up a WiFi network in `Hotspot` mode on an old PC running Ubuntu Mate. The computers on the network are unable to ping each other or even the hotspot. I believe it is an issue with IP assignment. How can I configure this? (A DHCP server, or a pre-assigned list of IP-MAC mappings, would both be fine, but I don't know where to start looking. I fiddled around with `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` to no avail.)

Comment: you can confirm or discount IP address issues just by inspecting the IP address of several devices on the hotspot, and determine whether they are all in the same network. More likely, the hotspot is performing AP Client isolation, which prevents users in coffee shops from trying to hack each other, and helps limit intrusion when someone cracks your wifi.

Comment: even when I only have one device connected, it is unable to ping the hotspot itself

Comment: that may be a differant problem. focus on two devices talking to each other for now. Secure wifi scenarios often prevent wireless users from accessing the router to protect the management instrumentation, and many firewalls block ping.  Are the devices able to connect through the wifi to the Internet?

Comment: I don't know (the hotspot isn't connected to the internet)

Comment: The hotspot is a file server, the only reason I want to connect to it is to transfer files